# Combine data from multiple cell in one cell with text

Tags: google-sheets

I have a row A with 200 text entries.

- A1 = "A1value"
- A2 = "A2value"
- A3 = "A3value"

  ...

I want to dynamicaly display in a single cell (text format) : ga=A1value,ga=A2value,ga=A3value, [...] ga=A200value etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `join` function:

[image]

`=JOIN(",ga=", A1:A3)`

for some regions semicolon is used:

`=JOIN(",ga="; A1:A3)`

next step: add first "ga=" manually:

`="ga="&JOIN(",ga=", A1:A3)`